# Terraform private azure load balancer issue

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

Iam trying to deploy an infrastructure with a private loadbalancer:

```
.....
resource "azurerm_lb" "private" {
name                = "${var.name}-${var.live}-private-lb"
location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
sku                 = var.sku

frontend_ip_configuration {
  name                          = "frontend"
  subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id != "" ? var.subnet_id : null
  private_ip_address            = (var.subnet_id != "" && var.private_ip != "") ? var.private_ip : null
  private_ip_address_allocation = var.subnet_id != "" ? (var.subnet_id == "" ? "Static" : "Dynamic") : null
 }
}
......
```

But i got the error message :

```
..../frontendIPConfigurations/frontend must reference either a Subnet, Public IP Address or Public IP Prefix." Details=[]
```

Why and how can i tackle this issue ? I don't know which configuration is missing.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An internal Load Balancer differs from a public Load Balancer, it has been assigned to a subnet and does not have a public IP address. As the error displayed, the frontend should reference **either** a Subnet, Public IP Address or Public IP Prefix, and the subnet should have existed when you reference. You could use the [data source subnet](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/subnet.html) to access information about an existing resource or create your subnet and VNet for your load balancer.

For example, the following can work for me.

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "mytestrg" 
}


variable "sku" {
  default = "basic"
}

variable "private_ip" {
  default = "172.19.0.100"
}

variable "env" {
  default="Static"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "test" {
  name                 = "default"
  virtual_network_name = "vnet1"
  resource_group_name  = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "test" {
  name                = "mytestlb"
  location            = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  sku                 = "${var.sku}"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                          = "frontend"
    subnet_id                     = "${data.azurerm_subnet.test.id}"
    private_ip_address            = "${var.env=="Static"? var.private_ip: null}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "${var.env=="Static"? "Static": "Dynamic"}"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are the best. Perfect answer